# Measure and compare differences between own server and CDN

Tags: jquery, performance, google-analytics, google-cdn

I have been serving my own jquery.js and recently stumbled upon the idea of using google's CDN.

I am very interested in switching to it because of its advertised reasons, but I want to measure its worth as well. (If it makes anyone wonder why, my site's traffic population consists of mainly a developing country where infrastructures tend to lack completeness and maturity (e.g. my own server may be closer to the closest cdn server to most visitors??), and where performance research reports tend to overlook in sampling (e.g. if anyone says CDN works great but have never tested it on 56k dialup connections, it would be invalid conclusion)

So my question is, can I measure the average time taken to download `http://mydomain.com/jquery.js` vs `<whatevercdnurl>/jquery.js` by tracking them using analytics?
Plus I can't load this script asynchronously (and I don't mind) so I'd expect to submit timing information measured manually..

Specifically, is the following testing method valid? (A/B test the jquery-1.8.0 url with Google CDN's)

```
<script type="text/javascript">before = new Date().getTime();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='/jquery-1.8.0.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  after = new Date().getTime();
  timeSpent = after - before;
  // Google Analytics _trackTiming call
</script>
```

Thanks for your kind perusal and any help is appreciated!

Comment: What browser you use? You can use firebug on mozzila or press F12 in chrome. On Network tab you can see average time for downloading specific scripts and other resources. You don't need to use any code...